# How to resolve the configuration problem with 2 application.properties in Springboot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, spring-data-jpa, h2

I have 2 application.properties in a Springboot project. One for the test(application) and the other for the application.

I dont understand the log here which is eventually throwing an error of not able to create the bean of the DB2 datasource. The idea is to create the bean of the H2 datasource while running the tests. However, the error shows that the error is due to the creation of the DB2 datasource bean. I have defined application-localtest.properties to establish the H2 database connection but from the log it seems that the bean for H2 datasource is not created. I think the application.properties file is overriding the application.localtest.properties file. In the log provided below it first states that activated "localtest" profile and then it states "localtest" won't apply and then the error is thrown.

> 2023-08-12 13:42:29.263  INFO 9516 --- [           main] d.k.d.v.a.BatchTest             : Starting VTZReportBatchTest using Java 11.0.14.1 on VM2300094 with PID 9516 (started by xx in xx\AppServer-xxx)
> 2023-08-12 13:42:29.265 DEBUG 9516 --- [           main] d.k.d.v.a.BatchTest             : Running with Spring Boot v2.7.9, Spring v5.3.25
> 2023-08-12 13:42:29.267  INFO 9516 --- [           main] d.k.d.v.a.BatchTest             : The following 1 profile is active: "localtest"
> 2023-08-12 13:42:29.269 DEBUG 9516 --- [           main] o.s.b.SpringApplication                  : Loading source class xxx.xxxx.Batch,class xxx.xxx.config.H2Test
> 2023-08-12 13:42:29.354 DEBUG 9516 --- [           main] b.c.c.ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor : Switching to legacy config file processing [[ConfigurationProperty@4a55a6e8 name = spring.config.use-legacy-processing, value = 'true', origin = class path resource [application-localtest.properties] - 2:37]]
> 2023-08-12 13:42:29.354 DEBUG 9516 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.c.ConfigFileApplicationListener  : Activated activeProfiles localtest
> 2023-08-12 13:42:29.354 DEBUG 9516 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.c.ConfigFileApplicationListener  : Loaded config file 'file:xxx/AppServer-xxx/target/classes/application.properties' (classpath:/application.properties)
> 2023-08-12 13:42:29.355 DEBUG 9516 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.c.ConfigFileApplicationListener  : Profiles already activated, '[localtest]' will not be applied
> 2023-08-12 13:42:29.355 DEBUG 9516 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.c.ConfigFileApplicationListener  : Loaded config file 'file:xxx/AppServer-xxx/target/test-classes/application-localtest.properties' (classpath:/application-localtest.properties) for profile localtest
> 2023-08-12 13:42:30.953  INFO 9516 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
> 2023-08-12 13:42:31.144  INFO 9516 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 164 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
> 2023-08-12 13:42:32.500  WARN 9516 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'getDB2Source' defined in class path resource [xxxx/xx/DatasourceConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'getDB2Source' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalDTD' is not recognized.
> 2023-08-12 13:42:32.535 DEBUG 9516 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :

My Test configuration class (H2Test) is as follows -

```
@TestConfiguration
@ActiveProfiles("localtest")
public class H2Test {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Value("org.h2.Driver")
    private String dbUrl;

    @Value("jdbc:h2:mem:test")
    private String dbDriverClass;
    @Value("sa")
    private String dbUser;

    @Primary
    @Bean(name="datasource")
    @Profile("localtest")
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean
    public DataSource getH2DataSource() throws Exception{

        System.out.println("___ DataSource construction started ___");

        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(dbDriverClass);
        dataSource.setUrl(dbUrl);
        dataSource.setUsername(dbUser);
        dataSource.setPassword("");

        ResourceDatabasePopulator rdp = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
        rdp.setScripts(new ClassPathResource("/test/data/Create_Tables.sql"));

        rdp.execute(dataSource);
        return dataSource;

    }
```

The test class is as follows -

```
@SpringBootTest(
        classes = { Batch.class}
)
@AutoConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(
        classes = {H2Test.class}
)
@ActiveProfiles("localtest")
public class BatchTest{
  
    String[] args={"xx", "xx","x","xxx","xxx"};

    @Test
    public void testMain() throws IOException{


          Batch batch =new Batch();
         Assertions.assertDoesNotThrow(()->Batch.main(args));

    }
}
```

I want to run the test by calling the main method of the application in the Batch.class and intend to create the bean of the H2 datasource with the application-localtest.properties while running the test. Batch. class is the class that contains the main method and the corresponding BatchTest.class provided above.

Comment: Can you try loading it explicitely such as:

@TestPropertySource(
  locations = "classpath:application-localtest.properties")

Comment: dataSource bean is not found even after adding  @TestPropertySource( locations = "classpath:application-localtest.properties")